# php zlib gzopen not exists

Tags: 14.04, php, zlib

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and php 5.5.9-1ubuntu4 (cli) (built: Apr  9 2014 17:08:27)

```
var_dump(extension_loaded('zlib')); => true
var_dump(function_exists('gzread')); => true
var_dump(function_exists('gzclose')); => true
```

But

```
var_dump(function_exists('gzopen')); => false
```

What's wrong ?

Thank you for ideas

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell (researching this all afternoon) gzopen() is now gzopen64() in php5.  I am still trying to find a way to map it locally without having to maintain code in 5,000 programs that call gzopen() instead.

Comment: Have any links to support your finding? It would make a nice addition to your answer.